# Why does np.save() take so much space on disk

Tags: python, numpy, keras

The numpy array which I am storing contains an image. The size of the image is 23.4 KB but the size of the .npy file is 4 MB

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img,img_to_array

image=load_img('image.JPEG')
array=img_to_array(image)
np.save('sample.npy',array)
```

Comment: I would expect JPEG compression to be a big part of it; I don't think that array you're building has any compression whatsoever.

Comment: what's the resolution of your image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> numpy.save()

- uncompressed binary file

if you need to compress it use

> numpy.savez_compressed()

- compressed using zipped archive

Comment: savez_compressed and savez may be zipping, but that doesn't really help in the case of float64 matrix of size (3,1000,1000). The size changes from ~25 MB to ~21MB

Answer (score 6):

Because `np` save it as a matrix, that means there is no compression. But `JPEG` is doubtlessly a compressed format. Maybe you can convert original image to `BMP`, and see its size as `BMP` is a format without compression.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the dtype of your np matrix. The image is probably quantized values (maybe uint) while the matrix maybe float64. Changing the dtype to uint should reduce space used