# why size of npy file is so huge as compare to jpg, png image

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

Hi there I just try that if we save image into npy file then it must take less size but that's not the case actually size of an image become 20 time bigger in some case 5 MB image converted to 100 MB .npy file anyone know the reason for this I try to search  for same but mostly answers is for that this .npy format is blazing fast for reading image file which I know so my thinking for saving image file as .npy is wrong but why
This is the code file I used to test my hypothesis.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import time

w,h = 200,200
data = []

def makeData(var):
    img = cv2.imread(f'{var}.jpg')
    print(img.shape)
    print(img.nbytes / 1024 / 1024)

    print('resize_img')

    resize_img = cv2.resize(img,(w,h))
    print(resize_img.shape)
    print(resize_img.nbytes / 1024 / 1024)


    print('save to npy file')

    return resize_img

    #np.save(f'{var}.npy',np.array(img))
    #np.save(f'{var}_resize.npy',np.array(resize_img))
    #cv2.imwrite(f'{var}_resize.jpg',resize_img)



def readImgData(var):
    img = cv2.imread(f'{var}.jpg')
    print(img.shape)

def readNPYData(var):
    data = np.load("data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
    print('Length of data',len(data))
    

varList = ['a','b','c','d','e']
t1 = time()
for var in varList:
    #resize_img = makeData(var)
    #data.append(resize_img)
    readImgData(var)
t2 = time()

print('Time Taken to read Image Data is,',t2-t1)

t1 = time()
for var in varList:
    readNPYData(var)
t2 = time()

print('Time Taken to read NPY Data is,',t2-t1)
    
    

#np.save('data.npy',data)
```

Comment: Image formats like jpg and png are compressed. Npy files are not compressed. Look into npz for compressed numpy files.

Comment: Ok I think Jpeg ,png and other format is already did compresseion but converting it into numpy definatly fasten the reading speed but increases the size 'No body cares about size in machine learning LOL'

Comment: @jakub thanks I just checked with compressed with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231119/why-does-np-save-take-so-much-space-on-disk and definitely results improve from 90 MB to 45 Mb but that's worst then 5Mb original image size